# If/else redundant code in ternary operator

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code works fine, but it looks like it could be optimized as it just reverses the ternary order. Any idea how to achieve that?

```
if ($("#advanced-search-panel").hasClass("hidden")) {
    adv_text.text(adv_text.text() == "Show advanced search" ? "Hide advanced search" : "Show advanced search");
}else{
    adv_text.text(adv_text.text() == "Hide advanced search" ? "Show advanced search" : "Hide advanced search");
}
```

Comment: Will `adv_text.text()` ever have anything other than those two strings?

Comment: @CertainPerformance, no, only Show/Hide

Answer (score 1):

Since `adv_text.text()` only has two possibilities - show and hide - the entire condition

```
if ($("#advanced-search-painel").hasClass("hidden")) {
```

is superfluous, because no matter whether the class exists or not, you want to toggle the text from show to hide, or from hide to show, depending on what the text currently is. Your code simplifies to

```
adv_text.text(
  adv_text.text() == "Show advanced search" ? "Hide advanced search" : "Show advanced search"
);
```

Another option would be to have an inline element for the part of the text that changes, so that you only have to check and change that.

```
<div><span class="adv-search-toggle-text">Show</span> advanced search</div>
```

```
const span = $('.adv-search-toggle-text');
span.text(span.text() === 'Show' ? 'Hide' : 'Show');
```

It sounds like the `hidden` class might have something to do with the text toggling above. If it does, there's a chance you could use CSS rules alone to have `Show` shown when the hidden class is applied, and `Hide` shown when the hidden class isn't applied.

Comment: @anvd If you know that the latter condition `adv_text.text() == "Hide advanced search"` will have precisely the opposite true/false value as the earlier condition `adv_text.text() == "Show advanced search"`, then your code is equivalent to what you get if you replace the latter condition with the earlier one while also swapping the two results in the second ternary operator.  Having made that change, now both branches of your outer if statement will contain the exact same line of code, proving that the outer if statement is redundant -- just as this answer says.

Comment: @anvd Do note however that if `adv_text.text()` is initially empty (or has some other value besides these two) -- contra to what you said above about it *always* being "Show/Hide" -- then you'd first need to set it to either "Hide advanced search" or "Show advanced search".

Comment: The initial string is "Show advanced search" but the panel can start already open. So this message needs to be overridden. Honestly I will stay with the dumb original solution to keep this simple

Answer (score 0):

As a first step: you want to have `"Show advanced search"` as a result exactly if both `$("#advanced-search-painel").hasClass("hidden")` and `adv_text.text() == "Show advanced search"` are true or both are false, so you could have:

```
adv_text.text(
    $("#advanced-search-painel").hasClass("hidden") == (adv_text.text() == "Show advanced search")
    ? "Hide advanced search"
    : "Show advanced search"
);
```

But as @CertainPerformance points out, with the constraint of `adv_text.text()` having only those two possible values, the `if` and `else` branch are achieving exactly the same, so there is no need for the `if` actually.